# Sorting a list inside an object using stream or collection

Tags: java, lambda, collections, stream

We had a scenario where we had to sort the Project object based on companyName.

```
class Department  {
    Project projectObj;
    ....
    getter..
    setters..
}

class Project {
    List<Company> companyList
    ....
    getter..
    setters..
}

class Company  {
    String companyName ;
    ....
    getter..
    setters..
}
```

The end result should be a report which will print the company info and it will be sorted on the base of company name. I cant fetch the list from db as I cant change the queries need to do it in Java itself.

I tried using Collection.Sort() but was not able to sort the list. The report was unsorted. How can i do it using streams or collection. Cannot separate the list as the object is used later.

What i tried.

```
 Collections.sort(deptObj.getProjectObj.getCompanyList(), Comparator.comparing(
            (Company c) -> c.getCompanyName()));
```

Comment: If you can't sort it correctly with `Collections.sort()` neither `.stream().sorted()...` will help.

Comment: What do you mean by *not able to sort*?

Comment: can that be because of hibernate as it doesn't allow the modification of model class object?

Comment: is it possible that there can be many records of Company in Project ? or it is oneToOne record?

Comment: @user7.. the report is printed in excel but after using collection.sort() the list remains unsorted. am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @Manasi ya company can have n number of records

Comment: You need to show the code that attempts to sort

Comment: @Suyash if company can have n number of record how can you sort project using company? and which company record to be used for comparing with differet project object ?

Comment: If you have "not working code", please put up a [mcve]. So please edit your question accordingly. Avoid putting more information into comments!

Comment: Why is it down voted?

Comment: OK, you included your code which "doesn't work", now please include in the question description of problem you are facing. Does your code not compile, throws exception, gives incorrect results (what was input/data and what result did you expect instead)?

Comment: @Pshemo... In my report i just need to get the company info sorted.

Comment: That code should do it. *How* do you recognize it doesn't? Put that info into your question, because this is probably where your problem is.

Comment: Your example still doesn't let us reproduce your problem. For instance we don't know what `deptObj.getProjectObj.getCompanyList()` does. If it returns *copy* of list `Project` instance holds, then you will sort only that copy. This means that when in other place you will call `deptObj.getProjectObj.getCompanyList()` you will get *another* (unsorted) copy. But that is just one of possible problems. To get proper answer provide proper [mcve]. If you would like others to spend their time on helping you, you must be willing to spend your own time on making helping you easier (or even possible).

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
Collections.sort(deptObj.getProjectObj.getCompanyList(), String::compareToIgnoreCase);
```

old answer:

You can have method in the Project class itself. You can call it that returns a sorted list of Company object. It sorts using Java 8's `stream` and `sorted` methods and `collect` it back into a List. It uses Comparator to sort based on a qualifier. Here qualifier being company name.

```
public class Project {

    private List<Company> companyList;
    //... other fieldsand getters/setters

    public List<Company> getSortedCompanies(){
        return this.companyList.stream()
        .sorted((company1, company2) ->
        company1.companyName().compareTo(company2.companyName()))
        .collect(toList()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.... i dont want to separate it in a list...can that be done inside the object itself...like collection.sort() does

Answer (score 0):

If there are many records of Company in Project it is difficult, if there is single record we can do

If data is fetched form database(as per your comment) it is best option to user database order by in query

If you want to do in code and have java 8

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(project  -> 
   (project.getCompanyList() != null && project.getCompanyList().size>0 )?project.getCompanyList().get(0): null));
```

Comment: thanks for the answers but there can be many records in list cant sort it from the db.

Comment: @Suyash If you have many records then you just need to add order by in query then database will sort it for you